# How to force the jquery UI autocomplete dropdown list to show using code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI to show a drop-down list of suggestions. I made it so that, when you start typing in the auto-complete input field, then after you stop typing for 1 second (it has an on key-up event, which reset if you type a new character in less than a second), it will make a Ajax request and get an XML response, then change the available tags of the input field.

The problem is that when I change the suggestions source, the menu doesn't appear in the input field. I want to force the menu to appear using jquery right after I set its new source.

Right now, to get it to appear, I need to type again, which then shows the menu, but at the same time, it gets another xml response, and then it gets messed up...

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call `search` method:

```
input.autocomplete( "search", input.val() );
```